# How do I install one of Github Pages' Jekyll themes for local preview?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I'm trying to install Github Pages' [Slate theme](https://github.com/pages-themes/slate) on my CentOS 7 VM so I can locally preview my *new* site using the `bundle exec jekyll serve` command.

I followed the instructions as best as I could.

- I changed the theme `minima` to `jekyll-theme-slate` in my `_config.yml` file.
- Then I changed `gem "minima", "~> 2.0"`  to `gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins` in my `Gemfile` file.

After that (since these are their only instructions), I ran `bundle exec jekyll serve` and it told me I had gems that weren't installed (duh), and suggested running `bundle install`.

- I ran `bundle install`, which told me there was a conflict in version types of the dependencies and it suggested that `bundle update` could potentially resolve that issue.
- No problem, I ran `bundle update`. A few plugins/features actually reverted versions here, but I got the Slate theme installed on my machine now, version `0.0.4` for whatever reason.

After that, I ran `bundle exec jekyll serve` again. I got this error:

```
Configuration file: /home/peri/my-site/_config.yml
Configuration file: /home/peri/my-site/_config.yml
jekyll 3.4.3 | Error:  Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
```

In a way, that error makes sense. For a custom theme to work, I probably need a tool to run their custom scripts. But first, I noticed [this extra section](https://github.com/pages-themes/slate#previewing-the-theme-locally) in the theme's installation instructions, which directly mentions being able to locally preview the site with that theme.

- I downloaded the source, instead of cloning it...I don't need the `.git` stuff do I?
- I edited the `script/bootstrap` file because `/usr/local` requires root and using `sudo` doesn't know about any binary called `gem` or `bundle`. I changed `gem` and `bundle` to their respective absolute paths and ran `sudo ./script/bootstrap` inside of `slate-master`.

Point of the story is, it didn't work for my `home/peri/my-site` directory when I ran `bundle exec jekyll serve`. Presumably, it's because they intended for the user's site to be integrated into their theme's source code? That doesn't seem intuitive or correct. So, I investigated [ExecJS](https://github.com/rails/execjs).

- I installed it. `gem install execjs`
- I added `gem "execjs", "2.7.0"` to my `Gemfile` file.

Got the same error as before.

> How am I supposed to install this Jekyll theme?

Comment: Do you have a JavaScript runtime?

Comment: Not that I know of, which is why I tried to install ExecJS.

Comment: You need something like node, v8, etc

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a try, thank you. With one of the ones you just mentioned, do I still need `ExecJS` in my `Gemfile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps after changing the theme in `_config.yml`:

1. `Gemfile` should have only this content:

   ```
   source "https://rubygems.org"
   gem "github-pages"
   ```
2. remove bundler current config: `rm -r .bundle/`
3. remove Gemfile.lock: `rm Gemfile.lock`
4. Install local dependencies in an isolated folder just for this website: `bundle install --path=vendor/bundle`
5. You won't have `post` and `page` and `home` themes, you will need to use just `default` in all your posts.
6. Generate and run server: `bundle exec jekyll s`

Comment: I took a handful of your suggestions and Dave's. You were right about bullet #5, I don't have those layouts anymore with the new theme. However, the main issue was not having a Javascript runtime. I downloaded Node.js and made a symbolic link to the `node` binary in `/usr/local/bin` and it works great now.